# Moving randomly a Character Horizontally in as3. .

Tags: flash, actionscript, coding-style, flash-cs5

I am just doing a small Game. I am just a beginner in actionscript. I want my character flying randomly from left to right or right to left on the top of the screen. and it comes randomly. . i dont have an idea about. Can anyone explain me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can let a movieclip go from left to right like this:

```
//the center point to move around
var center:Number = 512;

//the offset to move to the left and right (512 + 300 and 512 - 300)
var offset:Number = 300;

//the speed the object moves (higher = slower, lower = faster)
var speed:Number = 2000;

//create a object to move around, or just get something from the stage
var dragon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
dragon.graphics.beginFill(0);
dragon.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
dragon.graphics.endFill();
addChild(dragon);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter_frame);
function onEnter_frame(e:Event):void {
  var time:Number = new Date().valueOf() / speed;
  dragon.x = center + (Math.cos(time) * offset)
}
```

Comment: Hey Marigin, Ur code works fine. But my dragon doesnt move at al. . only the rectangle moves around. .

Comment: You need to change the dragon in my code with the reference to your dragon ofcourse

Comment: Thanks marijn. . I got it now correctly. But the thing is tat My dragon flys perfectly when coming from Right to left. And it flys in the reverse direction when it comes from left to Right. Is ther any way to transform it or rotate it in AS3 ?

Comment: yes, but that depends totally on the animation you want it to have.
Maybe you should take a loot at 3th party tweening scripts, like tweenLite (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), or Tweener (http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29

To get a random number. After this, use this number to determine if it's left or right (for instance, check the value for below the max / 2 (0.5 since it's a random generator between 0 and 1) and decide it's left or right and the other part will be for the other side). Then move your character accordingly by setting its coordinates.
However, if you make it move too little, too fast, it will result in weird movements. Depending on your game, you might have to make something more complicated based on the random element.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey Thanks for tat. . Is that The things comes randomly depending upon the grid ruler value. . I created a object like dragon to move around.

Answer (score 0):

I have did something like tis for now. . But i know thats not the right way. The thing is only three dragons pops from right to left if i do like this. I need more dragons to come randomly from right to left of the screen one by one .

```
//DRAGON Properties
var Dragon:dragon=new dragon();
Dragon.x+=1100;
Dragon.y=100;
addChild(Dragon);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dragonmove);

function dragonmove(e:Event):void{
Dragon.x-=2;
Dragon.y=100;
}

var Dragon1:dragon1=new dragon1();
Dragon1.x+=1900;
Dragon1.y=100;
addChild(Dragon1);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dragon1move);

function dragon1move(e:Event):void{
Dragon1.x-=2;
Dragon1.y=150;
}

var Dragon2:dragon2=new dragon2();
Dragon2.x+=2800;
Dragon2.y=100;
addChild(Dragon2);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dragon2move);

function dragon2move(e:Event):void{
Dragon2.x-=2;
Dragon2.y=50;
}
```

Comment: You better use Object Pooling, create a number of dragons (i.e. 20), and let them move randomly. Then when they leave the screen, re-use them. Watch this video: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=160

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ya all for your answer . got the work fine wit this.

```
//the center point to move around
var center:Number = 512;

//the offset to move to the left and right (512 + 300 and 512 - 300)
var offset:Number = 300;

//the speed the object moves (higher = slower, lower = faster)
 var speed:Number = 2000;

//create a object to move around, or just get something from the stage
var dragon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
dragon.graphics.beginFill(0);
dragon.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
dragon.graphics.endFill();
addChild(dragon);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter_frame);
function onEnter_frame(e:Event):void {
var time:Number = new Date().valueOf() / speed;
dragon.x = center + (Math.cos(time) * offset)
}
```